# Why Chrome does not highlight elements in Elements using Xpath

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

THis might sound stupid but I'm trying to understand why Chrome will not highligth this element in this page http://demo.guru99.com/test/selenium-xpath.html

The expression is:

//input[@name='uid']

And I can see the uid is a valid name

[image]

In fact it looks like there's no expression using any attribute that will yield anything

I might be doing something wrong I guess

Comment: If I paste this into the Chrome console, I get the expected element. So it's probably not a Chorme XPath problem. `document.evaluate("//input[@name='uid']", document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();`

Comment: This s a new defect added as part Chrome 84 deployment, the issue has already been notified to Chrome developers.

Comment: The next update of Chrome will have the fix. Meanwhile you can add `|*` to the search text and press Enter (or the prev/next buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is added as part of the chrome 84 deployment and already reported to the chrome developer. For time being you can use the console tab.

To test you XPath you can follow the below

```
$x("your xpath goes here")[0]
```

To test your CSS locator you can follow the below

```
$("your css goes here")[0]
```

Here is the open defect
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316

Comment: Can you add a link to the bug report?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107907

Comment: Or add `|*` to the search text and press Enter (or the prev/next buttons).